# Refresh access tokens when expired using Spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring, azure-active-directory, gateway

I am trying to find ways to refresh access tokens  if expired ,  before sending them to downstream applications from my Spring cloud gateway server.

I was looking over the web and I found something like this as
https://gist.github.com/tschlegel/62418600e04498d8c1db67ce5e1f17eb

Prior to this I was using the TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory from the Spring Cloud Gateway library which just passes the access tokens downstream without checking for expiration.

So I tried using the **TokenRelayWithTokenRefreshGatewayFilterFactory** as it seemed to work for most of them.

https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-cloud-security/issues/175

But I get the below error. (Debugging more into it looks like the error is thrown when sending the request from **"WebClientReactiveRefreshTokenTokenResponseClient"** class internally).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCAb6.png)

Note - I am using Microsoft Azure AD  as the authorization server with grant type as authorization code flow.

**2)  Is there any other alternate way I can try achieving this above requirement(refreshing expired access tokens).**

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have registered one Azure AD application and added **API permissions** by granting consent like below:

[image]

And I got **refresh token** along with access token via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST  https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:<appID>
grant_type:authorization_code
scope: offline_access user.read.all
code:code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
client_secret: secret
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I use the above access token to get my profile, I got the result successfully like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

[image]

When I try to fetch the profile again after an hour, I got error like below as token is expired

[image]

To refresh the expired access token, you can use below flow to generate new access token like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:appID
grant_type:refresh_token
refresh_token: 0.AVYA_in0zaI3eUqOQHrbrD-FUv //paste the refresh token that I got above
client_secret:client_secret //Mandatory if client is web app
```

**Response:**

[image]